# custom component/template not showing

Tags: javascript, aurelia

After playing around with Aurelia for a while, i'm trying to creating a custom component/template. However with below minimal code i still cant seem to show the message that is in `testcomponent.html`. I see the `<testcomponent></testcomponent>` in html DOM, however not the message `test`. What am i doing wrong?

**integrationcomponent.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="./forms/testcomponent"></require>
    <h1>first page</h1>
    <testcomponent></testcomponent>
</template>
```

**testcomponent.js**

```
export class TestComponent {

    constructor() {


    }

}
```

**testcomponent.html**

```
<template>
    <p>test</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classname is TestComponent; this tells Aurelia to look for test-component.html and test-component.js.

I think you can rename the class to 'Testcomponent' as well.

Aurelia is Convention over Configuration so you need to know the conventions.

Aren't there any error messages in the console?

Comment: No error messages in the console, but worked after i renamed

Comment: its just weird because of i have other cases where above naming with the camelCase works just fine and there is no `-` between the html file name aswell